# Deleting certain rows from a 2D list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am trying to know the best way to delete/manipulate a certain row(s) from my 2D arraylist. Following is the sample list:

```
 [ [Facebook, Bob, Mark , Yes],
    [Facebook, Bob, Priscilla, Yes],
    [Tesla, Bill, Elon, Yes],
    [Tesla, Bill, Maye, Yes],
    [Apple, Jim, Tim, Yes] ]
```

Basically, I don't want duplicates because I need to work on just list.get(0) and list.get(1) so I want a resulting list that just gives me something like:

```
[[Facebook, Bob],[Tesla,Bill],[Apple, Jim]]
```

that gives me a list of only the first two unique elements from the child of the 2D ArrayList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd stream the list, take the first two values from each list, take the unique results and collect them:

```
List<List<String>> data = /* data */ ;

List<List<String> result =
    data.stream()
        .map(l -> l.subList(0, 2))
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: ahh.. couldn't think of the collect approach! I was resorting to unnecessarily creating multiple for loops. Thanks! I'll try this one :)

Comment: `Set<List<String>` -> `Set<List<String>>`.  `.unique()` -> `.distinct()`.  `Collectors.toList()` -> `Collectors.toSet()`.

Comment: @saka1029 too late for my blood, apparently :-( Thanks for pointing those out - edited and fixed.

Comment: @saka yeah I figured that out when trying it! was about to comment the same!! Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly (Creating an array based on certian columns of another) What you can do is write a script that loops through each array and adds the item of that spot into another array. For example

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<{ITEM CLASS}>> cpy = new ArrayList<ArrayList<{ITEM CLASS>>();
for(int i = 0; i < List.Length; i++)
{
   cpy.Add(new ArrayList<{ITEM CLASS}>);
   for(int j = 0; j < List.get(0).Length; j++)
     {
         if(j == CopyIndex)
         {
             cpy.get(i).Add(List.get(i).get(j));
         }
     }

}
```

Or something like that ^ (I havent bug tested that so theres a chance it might not work but thats the general concept)